# How can I subtract one surface from another?

Tags: plotting, regions

I have one surface for which I have an analytical solution, and another represented by a list of 3D points. My question is: how can I plot the part of one that lies outside the other?

The first surface:

```
R = 1;
Ω = Disk[{0, 0}, {R, R}];
θ = 1;
G = 1;
Φ = 1/2 G θ R^2 (1 - x^2/R^2 - y^2/R^2);
Plot3D[Φ, {x, y} ∈ Ω, 
  PlotStyle -> None, 
  PlotTheme -> "Detailed", Mesh -> {25}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "ϕ(x,y)"}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Courier New"]]
```

[image]

The second surface:

```
circle = 
  {{(2 - Sqrt[3])/2, 0.5, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, 
   {(2 - Sqrt[3])/2, 1.5, 0}, {0.5, (2 - Sqrt[3])/2, 0}, 
   {0.5, 0.5, 0.3774047358083551`}, {0.5, 1, 0.4599364905389034`}, 
   {0.5, 1.5, 0.3774047358083551`}, {0.5, (2 + Sqrt[3])/2, 0}, 
   {1, 0.`, 0}, {1, 0.5, 0.4599364905389034`}, 
   {1, 1, 0.5849364905389033`}, {1, 1.5, 0.4599364905389034`}, 
   {1, 2, 0}, {1.5, (2 - Sqrt[3])/2, 0}, 
   {1.5, 0.5, 0.3774047358083551`}, {1.5, 1, 0.4599364905389034`}, 
   {1.5, 1.5, 0.3774047358083551`}, {1.5, (2 + Sqrt[3])/2, 0}, 
   {(2 + Sqrt[3])/2, 0.5, 0}, {2, 1, 0}, {(2 + Sqrt[3])/2, 1.5, 0}}
ListPlot3D[circle, 
  PlotStyle -> None, 
  PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
  Mesh -> {3, 3}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "ϕ(x,y)"}, 
  InterpolationOrder -> 2, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Courier New"]]
```

[image]

Comment: What is `kor` ?

Comment: @rasher sorry, i corrected, kor=circle

Comment: I don't understand in what sense "subtract" or "withdrawn."  The domains are different, so do you want to subtract the smaller circle from the greater, leaving a hole?  Do you want to subtract the ordinates over the intersection of the domains?  Likewise, do you want an interpolation of the "another" and subtract it from `Φ` over the intersection of the domains?  Something else, perhaps?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I want to substract the smaller circle from the greater, leaving a hole, like you wrote firstly. And that way get the difference between the two circle. The domain is R=1 at the circles. (Both of them) Then I want to present it on a circle domain with interpolation.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, **vote** them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to **accept** the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: (It seemed perhaps the standard welcome had not been extended to you, yet.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks

Comment: @xzczd Yes, thanks for the answer

Comment: ……我想我猜的没错吧？你的母语是汉语吧？你真的明白accept the answer和click the checkmark sign的意思吗？也就是说，至今为止你得到的答案没有一个让你满意的吗？

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this is what you mean:

```
Plot3D[Φ, {x, y} ∈ 
  RegionDifference[DiscretizeRegion@Ω, 
   ConvexHullMesh[circle[[All, 1 ;; 2]]]], PlotStyle -> None, 
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed", Mesh -> {25}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "ϕ(x,y)"}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Courier New"]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But perhaps I subtracted them in the wrong order, or plotted the wrong function.  In which case, maybe this:

```
ListPlot3D[circle, PlotStyle -> None, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
 Mesh -> {3, 3}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "ϕ(x,y)"}, 
 InterpolationOrder -> 2, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Courier New"],
 RegionFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y}, {x, y} ∉ Ω]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]